# What is the surest way to get PyCharm to use updated python packages from requirements.txt file in a project?

Tags: python, pycharm, requirements.txt

Pycharm community edition 2017.3 doesn't seem to have a way to Install requirements.txt packages from a project except that it pops up `Install` link on the top right corner once in a while and even then doesn't install all packages from my requirements.txt. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: can't you just run `pip install -r requirements.txt` or do you want to specifically install dependencies from Pycharm?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf want to do it from Pycharm so I can debug from Pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the best way to ensure this is to open a terminal in Pycharm. On that terminal, if you run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it installs all the dependencies present in that file. After this, if you run Pycharm debugger, it will work and not complain about missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the best way is to use virtualenv with all your project dependecies installed there. Then you can [configure PyCharm's project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html) to use interpreter from your virtual environment.

Comment: I was doing that and still the debugger would complain some dependencies were not missing. When I checked, it seemed like it kept using some different versions previously installed as part of that virtual environment in-spite of my requirements.txt asking for a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

A contemporary way of doing this would be to use `pipenv`. It doesn't use a `requirements.txt` file anymore but instead a `Pipfile` and a `Pipfile.lock`, but it can read a `requirements.txt` input file of an existing project.

1. Install pipenv globally: `pip install pipenv`
2. Add your project folder to PyCharm
3. Set the project's interpreter to a new pipenv environment by going to

   - File > Settings > Project: your-project > Project Interpreter
   - In the top right, click the gear icon and click 'Add'
   - In the left sidebar click 'Pipenv Environment'
   - Select the desired Python version
   - Click OK
4. Done! PyCharm will set up a virtual environment, and install packages found in existing `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` files.